# If [ComboBox] Is Null Statement in VBA/Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, forms, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a form with one ComboBox (`YearToBeBuilt`) and two textBox fields (`Cost` and `YearofExpenditureCost`). All controls are linked to a main table and the table is updated once the selections/entries have been made on the form.

I have written a procedure in VB called `ReCalcIt()`which performs the following procedure when called:

```
Private Sub ReCalcIt()
If Me.YearToBeBuilt = "" Then
    Me.YearofExpenditureCost = Me.Cost
Else
    Me.YearofExpenditureCost = Me.Cost * (1 + 0.031) ^ (Me.YearToBeBuilt - 2010)
End If
End Sub
```

When I wrote this *I thought* that this would do the following:

If the ComboBox `[YearToBeBuilt]` is blank (e.g.-no selection made) then
the textbox `[YearOfExpenditureCost]` will return the value of the TextBox `[Cost]`.  Else, the calculation for `YearofExpenditureCost` is performed.

*But this is not working the way it should*

What am I doing wrong?  I am a VBA n00b so perhaps my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: Do you really want to use an exponent for the last part of your calculation? You realize that `Me.Cost * (1 + 0.031) ^ (Me.YearToBeBuilt - 2010)` is the equivalent of x^N where N is the result of the difference between YearToBeBuilt and 2010, so that is if N=3, it will be Me.Cost * (1 + 0.031) cubed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with

```
If Len(Me.YearToBeBuilt & vbNullString) = 0
```

So the code will look like this:

```
Private Sub ReCalcIt()
If Len(Me.YearToBeBuilt & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    Me.YearofExpenditureCost = Me.Cost
Else
    Me.YearofExpenditureCost = Me.Cost * (1 + 0.031) ^ (Me.YearToBeBuilt - 2010)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're awesome--that did exactly what I wanted it to do!  Thanks so much!  So because I am trying to understand this...basically that blank selection in the combobox is being interpreted as a string value?  So you have to tell the form that if the string value = 0 then do this...etc. Else...etc.?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Interpret it as a string, see the length of it and check if it is 0. I think it should work also without the vbNullString part - you should test it, but it is safer this way.

Comment: Interesting--thanks!  Fyi--the & vbNullString is necessary for my situation...I tested it and it did not work without that included.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to say:

```
If IsNull(MyControl) Then
```

See also: [Access VBA: If Form Value <> NULL then run query else, end if. - not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751233/access-vba-if-form-value-null-then-run-query-else-end-if-not-doing-anythi/3751399#3751399)

Comment: Recent versions of Access default to allowing ZLS in the table designer. I don't know if this leads to the storage of ZLS's unless you do something specific or not, but using just Not IsNull() is only going to work 100% reliably for fields that disallow ZLS.

Comment: I have tested with Access 2010 and a form based on a table that was deliberately set up to allow ZLS. Even when a field (column) bound to such a control is space-filled, the control is returned by If IsNull(ctl).

Comment: Really? Well, that seems like a bug to me. What if you're using a Null as your default value (not known) and ZLS to mean "known to be blank"? If a control bound to that field returns Null regardless of which value is stored, it completely negates the value of allowing the storage of ZLS's. Hmm. reading again, you say if it's got spaces it's returned as Null, too? That's truly worrisome to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this might be dependent on the format of the combo box?  If it's a number, then

```
If Len(Me.YearToBeBuilt & vbNullString) = 0
```

doesn't work.  Because the Me.YearToBeBuilt has a value of 0, and so the above returns 1.

I'm wondering if there is a more robust method?  Maybe

```
Me.YearToBeBuilt.ListIndex = -1
```